# Adjust stereo separation for THREE.js StereoEffect or CardboardEffect?

Tags: three.js, google-cardboard, stereo-3d, virtual-reality

Working with WebGL via THREE.js and stereoscopic imaging. However the results are mixed at best. While I can see some stereo separation, it is fairly small. Anyone know how to increase the distance between the two "cameras" using the THREE.js StereoEffect and CardboardEffect?